# Make % jump between identical delimiters

Tags: filetype-tex, delimiter-matching

I use Vim to edit LaTeX files frequently. I want to use `%` to jump between matching `$` which can be used to delimit where mathematical expressions are written.

I have tried using matchit and, separately, I have tried using a filetype.vim (`tex.vim`) file to add a match to the `matchpairs` variable (`au FileType tex setmps+=$:$`). I have managed to get both attempts to jump from the `$`. However, the match that is found is for a different delimiter.

For example, considering the string `$ { test text } $`, placing my cursor over the first `$` and pressing `%` would jump me to the closing `}`, not the last `$`. Continued use of `%` jumps me between `{` and `}`. Thus, I am stuck inside the match that I want to consider.

Does anyone know how I might accomplish a jump from the first `$` to the last `$`?

Comment: If both are on the same line, you could just type `f$`, and then `;` and `,` to jump between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you ask is possible, but the solution is nontrivial. Both [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box) and [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) has implemented solutions for this, see here:

- [LaTeX-Box/ftplugin/latex-box/motion.vim:57](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box/blob/master/ftplugin/latex-box/motion.vim#L57) (`s:FindMatchingPair`)
- [vimtex/autoload/vimtex/motion.vim:303](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/autoload/vimtex/motion.vim#L303) (`s:highlight_matching_pair`)

These functions are run by autocommands whenever the cursor is moved, see [here (LaTeX-Box)](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box/blob/master/ftplugin/latex-box/motion.vim#L167) and [here (vimtex)](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/autoload/vimtex/motion.vim#L19). The original matchparen plugin is disabled, and the LaTeX-specific function, e.g. `s:highlight_matching_pair`, is enabled as a custom matchparen-plugin. Note that both these functions also enable matching of other LaTeX-delimiters such as `begin/end` pairs and pairs like `\left(..\right)`.

**Note**: The links above are linked to line numbers in evolving codes. These line numbers might change in the future. The function names will probably stay the same.

**Note**: Other LaTeX-plugins might also implement this feature.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of vimtex.

Comment: Thanks, Karl, for your explanation. I understand, now, that I won't be adding a couple lines to my .vimrc to implement this functionality. I use vim-latex as my current vim plugin for editing LaTeX files. I'm considering forking vim-latex to improve it. If I do this, I might introduce something like your ``s:highlight_matching_pair`` or LaTeX-Box's ``s:FindMatchingPair``. I see that both plugins require a separate logic branch (if statement) to process if the delimiter being matched is a '$', or not. It's special.

Comment: Personally I don't recommend forking vim-latex (aka LaTeX-Suite), instead I would suggest you open a pull request [here](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex). Personally I don't like vim-latex, mostly because it is huge and difficult to improve and customize.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$` match is ignored, `%` searches forward for the first character in a pair that it knows about: so it finds `{` and then the matching `}`, and moves between them.

From `:h mps`:

> Only character pairs are allowed that are different,
>     thus you cannot jump between two double quotes.

One solution would be: to use the 'matchit' plugin (which allows for regular expressions as pairs, but has the same start != end delimiter) AND use the LaTeX math delimiters `\(` `\)`, which are different. Or, define two new TeX different commands for start & end inline math environment, that both resolve to `$`, and use them as pairs.

So, you can do in your `vimrc`:

```
runtime! macros/matchit.vim
```

And, for TeX files (e.g. in a function called from a `BufEnter` autocmd):

```
let b:match_words = '\\(:\\)'
```

---

If you *have* to use the `$` sign, you can cheat a little and use this:

```
let b:match_words = '\s\$:\$\s'
```

... which will match a `$` preceded by space as start delimiter with a `$` followed by a space as end delimiter. But then you'll have to be consistent inside your formulas and use no space after the start delimiter, or before the end one. E.g.:

```
 ␣$\cos (2\theta) = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta$␣
```

Comment: Vim already knows which `$` characters are opening and which are closing because it highlights math segments. Could the information used by highlighting be leveraged for that improved `%` command?

Comment: If you open `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim` and search for `\$`s (heh), you'll see comments like this: «The $..$ and $$..$$ make for impossible sync patterns (one can't tell if a "$$" starts or stops a math zone by itself) The following grouptheres coupled with minlines above help improve the odds of good syncing.» and «4. There is no match-syncing for $...$ and $$...$$; hence large equation blocks constructed that way may exhibit syncing problems (there's no difference between begin/end patterns)». Maybe if you use text objects instead, e.g.: https://github.com/gibiansky/vim-latex-objects

Comment: To reuse existing syntax highlighting, but still with text-objects, you also have: https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-syntax, which defines a `textobj-syntax-i` as "the syntax highlighted item under the cursor". Then, for example, you can visually select the `$...$` as math object, and if you hit `o`, move cursor to the other end of the visual selection. But still doesn't answer your suggestion of implementing `%` from  syntax highlight rules ... I would like to see a vim guru coming up with some idea.

Comment: Both vimtex and LaTeX-Box use the syntax group to determine the boundaries of `$...$` as suggested by @Gilles.

Comment: Another reason to use vimtex, then :) Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Add the line

```
runtime! macros/matchit.vim
```

to your `vimrc` and into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` the lines

```
let b:match_words = get(b:, 'match_words', &l:matchpairs)
      \ ',' . '\%(^\|[ (/]\)\zs\\(' . ':' . '\\)\ze\%($\|[ )/.\,;\:?!\-]\)' .
      \ ',' . '\%(^\|[ (/]\)\zs\\\[' . ':' . '\\\]\ze\%($\|[ )/.\,;\:?!\-]\)' .
      \ ',' . '\%(^\|[ (/]\)\zs\$[^$ ]' . ':' . '[^$ ]\zs\$\ze\%($\|[ )/.\,;\:?!\-]\)' .
      \ ',' . '\%(^\|[ (/]\)\zs\$\$' . ':' . '\$\$\ze\%($\|[ )/.\,;\:?!\-]\)' .
      \ ',' . '\%(^\s*\)\zs\\begin{\(\w\+\*\?\)}' . ':' . '\%(^\s*\)\zs\\end{\1}' .
```

This lets you jump between TeX math and environment delimiters by `%` (but isn't yet entirely robust).

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using the `vimtex` plugin which is in active development and provides a lot of nice TeX features. You might check it out.